# What does "Take care sweets" mean?

Tags: meaning, expressions, synonyms

A good friend wrote me an email and at the end she added *Take care sweets*.

I guess it's something good, but not sure what is the exact meaning.
I searched a little bit what does that mean and didn't find anything.

So, what is the meaning of this expression and what would be alternative to that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Take care" means take care of yourself, and it is a not-uncommon way of saying goodbye. "Sweets" is you.

A comma would have helped, but I guess commas are pretty rare in texts.

Comment: And what would be an alternative saying with the same meaning? How is *sweets* me?

Comment: Perhaps an individual expression for darling or sweetheart.

Comment: Yes, 'sweets' is a term of endearment, so your friend (who might possibly want to become more than a friend :-))  could equally well have written "take care, honey" - it's really two terms, "take care" being a fairly neutral expression of good wishes, often said instead of "goodbye".

Comment: @jamesqf but note that the use of terms of endearment between non-partners is highly variable (see my answer at http://english.stackexchange.com/a/293430/48571 and the discussion following it)

Answer (score 1):

"Sweets" is short for sweetheart.

Answer (score 1):

**'Take care'** is an abbreviation of take care of yourself. It is just a little way to show you care about how they are doing and it is acceptable to say to friends, family and acquaintances.

**'Sweets'** is referring to a nickname she has for you. It is a term of endearment such as darling, sweetheart, sugar, pumpkin

If she's single and you are also, ask her out. You might have a good chance. Or you can always just laugh it off.